# If $A=[0,1)$ then show that its interior is $(0,1)$.

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that if $A=[0,1)$ then its interior is $(0,1)$. I know that $int(A) \subset A$, and that $\forall x \in int(A)$ $\exists R>0 $ such that $B(x,R) \subset A$. Thus immediately we see that $0 \notin int(A)$ because $\not \exists R>0$ such that $B(0,R)\subset A$.

What I struggle to do is to show that the final set is equal to $(0,1)$.

Comment: Put it this way. By definition,$$int(A)=\{x\in A: x\text{ is an interior point of}  A\}.$$ Now, every $x\in (0,1)$ is an interior point of $A$, as suggested by Arthur below. But as what you have said, $0\notin int(A)$ So, what can be said then to $int(A)$? Well, precisely, the members of $int(A)$ are only those members of the open interval $(0,1)$. Hope this solves your struggle.

Comment: Note that what you've described as the interior is technically just any open set contained in $[0,1)$. To make it the real definition of the interior, you have to add that it is the _largest_ such set.

Comment: @Arthur Are you referring your comment to me?--:D

Comment: @juniven No, at the OP. Sorry, that was vague. User401855: Look at my previous comment.

Comment: @user401855 I think you really need to read this http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do what you apparently already know you should do: Take an $x \in (0,1)$, and show that there is an $R > 0$ (i.e. *find* an $R$ that works, like $R = x/2$, which almost works) such that $B(x, R)\subseteq (0,1)$.

Answer (score 3):

Draw a picture : let $x \in (0,1)$ and $R=\frac{1}{2} \min\{x,1-x\}$.

Now show: $B(x, R)\subseteq (0,1)$